# Make different editions of an application with single code base

Tags: c#, .net, version, desktop-application, windows

I have developed an application for Windows desktop (in WPF). Let's assume this application has 50 features and let's call it **ULTIMATE** application.

I have another client which demands application with 30 features. Let's call this **PROFESSIONAL**

Application with 20 features, let's call it **BASIC**

Now, all I want is to maintain a single source code for all the editions.

My intention is that users with the **BASIC** edition can't use/see features available in **PROFESSIONAL** edition, and so on.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to use conditional compilation or something else?

Comment: This question is too broad.  Please narrow it down to a *specific* questioni.

Comment: License all features using FlexLM, RLM or any other licensing tool. You can control features using license file you provide.

Comment: You might want to store it in some sort of license key.

Comment: Thanks all for your guidance... @rory.ap in what sense do you want me to narrow this question. Can you please elaborate a little bit

Comment: @rory.ap you must know Microsoft does similar thing with their Windows OS lineup and also for Visual studio. Also some anti virus vendors does similar thing by providing free and paid license version.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is handled based on the product key. The algorithms for generating and reading the version depends developer to developer.

Lets take a simple example your product keys start by prefixing it's version e.g. - 
Ultimate version starts with "U" and will look like - Uxxxxxxxxxxxx
Professional version starts with "P" and will look like - Pxxxxxxxxxxxx
and so on.

Now when your application is loaded, you need to Enable/Disable OR Show/Hide the menus based on the product key version.

This is helpful, when your customer wan't to upgrade their version, you just need to release new product key which will be updated in the application & your software will work with the unlocked features.

Comment: Thanks alot... Is not there some way to make different builds depending upon the edition, 3 builds for 3 editions.